# What does WebDeploy 2.0 install?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-deployment, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I am purposing using WebDeploy 2.0 in my organization, and the question has been raised to me, What allEXE's/DLL's/Registry keys does installing this product put on the server. Is there a place that I can find that information?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own answer. Just in case any one else is looking for this information, I was able to find it by running the WebDeploy MSI through MSIExec with the logging option.

Thanks